# String Combination Without Using used letter again with given lenght of string

Tags: php

For example I have this string "qwertyuiopas"
and the length to be returned is : 5

How can i make a function that would return all possible 5 character strings from the given text above?

`example:
qwert
werty
ewryt
... and so on`

the letter should not be used again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function getSubStrings($string, $subStringLength) {

    $subStrings = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string) - $subStringLength; $i++) {
        $subStrings[] = substr($string, $i, $subStringLength);
    }

    return $subStrings;
}

// Testing

$string = "qwertyuiopas";
$length = 5;

var_dump(getSubStrings($string, $length));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir but this function is very limited. It does not return all the possible combinations like "tqrts". I mean all posible combinations sir... I think your function will just return a very few.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your requirement. 'tqrts' is good, even if you repeat the 't'? Give me precise requirements and I will try again. Please clarify the repeating 't'. Thanks.

Comment: im sory sir... "tqrts" wrong. I mean "tqrps" or any 5 letter string that character is from the given letters... THank you in advance sir....